# Какой у внутренней памяти адрес в файловой системе?

Tags: android, android-sdk, память

Какой у внутренней памяти адрес в файловой системе? И как его получать програмным путём? Для внешней памяти всё ясно: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. А вот как с внутренней быть не понятно.

Суть задачи в следующем:
Необходимо искать определённый тип файлов в файловой системе, с внешней памятью проблем нету, всё ищет всё работает. А к внутренней пробиться не могу. Через x-plore находил адреса и пробывал их использовать (`/storage/sdcard1`, `/storage/sdcard2`, `/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1`, `/mnt/sdcard2`, `/mnt/shell/emulated/0`), но не один адрес не работает или я просто не могу к нему пробиться через защиту!?

P.S. адрес внешней `/storage/sdcard0`

P.S.S. Видел на разных устройствах разные адреса монтирования памяти. Соответственно нужно получить его программно.

Comment: Каждый вендор монтирует и встроенную и съёмную флеш-память как ему заблагорассудится и даже `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` на одном аппарате возвращает встроенную, на другом съёмную.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под *внутренней памятью*?

Comment: Непосредственно тот раздел внутренней памяти, в котором хранится вся информация пользователя: фотографии, картинки, аудио, видео записи, документы, инсталяторы и составляющие приложений и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список всех внешних хранилищь (По умолчанию в телефоне которая + `SDCard`), я смог получить на `Samsung Galaxy A5 2017` с помощью с кода:

```
File[] externalStorageFiles = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this,null);
for(File file : externalStorageFiles) {
     String root = getRootOfExternalStorage(file);
     Log.d("myTag", "root = " + root);
}

private String getRootOfExternalStorage(File file) {
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return path.replaceAll("/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/files", "");
}
```

На новых версия `Android`, не забывайте предоставить [динамические разрешения](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Для получения доступа к внутренней памяти только своего приложения можно получить доступ с помощью `Context.getFilesDir()`. Доступа к внутренней памяти других приложений по умолчанию нет. Нужен `root`.
Еще можете посмотреть вот эти ответы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982338), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648873), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871043), но мне они путь определяли не верно.

Comment: Спасибо, возвращает оба известных мне пути, идеально. Только вот ещё проблема, как пробиться к внутренней памяти, так как адрес есть, но при попытке доступа к ней я получаю ответ об несуществующем пути к директории. Может я какое разрешение не дал?

Comment: @Valeriy подтвердите пожалуйста галочкой, что ответ вам помог

Comment: Пересмотрел все возможные разрешения в андроид студио, но подходящего ничего не нашел.

Comment: @Для доступа к внутренней памяти своего приложения дополнительные разрешения не нужны. Вероятно путь не правильный. Попробуйте найти решение сначала в готовых ответах, если не получится, создайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать, если не найду, буду создавать вопрос. потому как эти два вопроса искал вместе и уже не знаю где копнуть. Пробовал использовать получаемый адрес, также пробовал добавлять к адресу адрес стандартных папок типа Documents через константы "DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS", но путь все равно не существует.

Comment: @Valeriy тут нужно смотреть на код, которым вы это делаете. Смотреть на результат который вы получаете. Увидеть конкретную ошибку. Лучше тогда создайте вопрос и все хорошо опишите

Comment: Я извиняюсь, может я не верно составил вопрос, нужен доступ не к внутренней памяти приложения, а непосредственно к внутренней памяти телефона, где хранятся личные данные пользователя, а также данные приложений которые не удаляются после его удаления, например "/storage/sdcard1", при этом адрес флешки: "/storage/sdcard0"

Comment: Динамическое разрешение предоставляли приложению? Если нет, в ответе есть ссылка

Comment: У меня андроид 4,4. Да я переходил по ссылке и изучал вопрос, но там необходимо вписать разрешение, но я не знаю какое, ведь разрешение для внешней памяти работает стабильно из манифеста. И доступ к флешке есть. А к  "/storage/sdcard1" нету.